# Unsuccessful in using scrapy to load an already filtered RSS feed

Tags: python, xml, scrapy, rss

For reference see my code below:

```py
import scrapy

headers = \
{'Host': 'log.rlsbb.cc',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/110.0',
'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'Connection': 'keep-alive',
'Referer': 'https://log.rlsbb.cc/',
'Cookie': 'filters=foreign-movies,movies,tv-shows,old-movies,_foreign-movies_f-webrip,_foreign-movies_f-dvdrip-bdrip,\
_foreign-movies_f-bluray-720p,_foreign-movies_f-bluray-1080p,_movies_bluray-1080p,_movies_bluray-720p,_movies_bdrip,\
_movies_webrip,_movies_dvdrip,_movies_4k-uhd,_tv-shows_top,_tv-shows_tv-packs,_movies_old,_foreign-movies_f-old',
'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
'Sec-GPC': '1',
'DNT': '1',
'TE': 'trailers'}



class ScrapeRlsBBRssSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'scrape_rlsbb_rss'
    allowed_domains = ['log.rlsbb.cc/feed']
    start_urls = ['http://https://log.rlsbb.cc/feed/']

    custom_settings={ 'FEED_URI': f"{name}_%(time)s.json",
                      'FEED_FORMAT': 'json'}

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'https://log.rlsbb.cc/feed/',
        ]

        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse, headers=headers)

    def parse(self, response):
        for post in response.xpath('//channel/item'):
            yield {
                'title' : post.xpath('title//text()').extract_first(),
                'link': post.xpath('link//text()').extract_first(),
                'pubDate' : post.xpath('pubDate//text()').extract_first(),
                'category': post.xpath('category//text()').extract_first(),
            }
```

I have already filtered my [RSS feed](https://log.rlsbb.cc/feed) using the provided option (gear icon) on the [website](https://log.rlsbb.cc/).
When I press the RSS icon to get the feed link, it shows that link above with the required filtered links.
I then used the above feed link in scrapy to download that RSS XML. The output did not work  as it contained all the unfiltered as well as some filtered links. I then applied the filters in the cookies field of the headers (see code) and it returns an empty file.
What did I do wrong or misunderstood?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing the filters in as a parameter of the header, you should isolate just the filter cookie into it's own dictionary, and then feed that to the `cookies` parameter of your request.

For example:

```
import scrapy

cookie = {"filters": ("foreign-movies,movies,tv-shows,old-movies,_foreign-movies_f-webrip,_foreign-movies_f-dvdrip-bdrip,"
"_foreign-movies_f-bluray-720p,_foreign-movies_f-bluray-1080p,_movies_bluray-1080p,_movies_bluray-720p,_movies_bdrip,"
"_movies_webrip,_movies_dvdrip,_movies_4k-uhd,_tv-shows_top,_tv-shows_tv-packs,_movies_old,_foreign-movies_f-old")}


class ScrapeRlsBBRssSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'scrape_rlsbb_rss'
    allowed_domains = ['log.rlsbb.cc/feed']
    custom_settings={ 'FEED_URI': f"{name}_%(time)s.json",
                      'FEED_FORMAT': 'json'}

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'https://log.rlsbb.cc/feed/',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse, cookies=cookie)

    def parse(self, response):
        for post in response.xpath('//channel/item'):
            yield {
                'title' : post.xpath('title//text()').extract_first(),
                'link': post.xpath('link//text()').extract_first(),
                'pubDate' : post.xpath('pubDate//text()').extract_first(),
                'category': post.xpath('category//text()').extract_first(),
            }
```

OUTPUT

```
2023-02-22 17:07:50 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://log.rlsbb.cc/feed/>
{'title': 'Support US', 'link': 'https://log.rlsbb.cc/support-us/', 'pubDate': 'Fri, 01 Jan 2021 22:26:26 +0000', 'category': 'Offtopic'}
2023-02-22 17:07:50 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://log.rlsbb.cc/feed/>
{'title': 'Studio C S16E01-E09 WEB x264-DARK', 'link': 'https://log.rlsbb.cc/studio-c-s16e01-e09-web-x264-dark/', 'pubDate': 'Thu, 23 Feb 2023 00:49:02 +0000', 'category': 'TV Shows'}
2023-02-22 17:07:50 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://log.rlsbb.cc/feed/>
{'title': 'Pretty Hard Cases S03E08 720p WEBRip x264-BAE', 'link': 'https://log.rlsbb.cc/pretty-hard-cases-s03e08-720p-webrip-x264-bae/', 'pubDate': 'Thu, 23 Feb 2023 00:35:50 +0000', 'category': 'TV
Shows'}
2023-02-22 17:07:50 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://log.rlsbb.cc/feed/>
{'title': 'Gods Country 2022 1080p BluRay x264 DTS-MT', 'link': 'https://log.rlsbb.cc/gods-country-2022-1080p-bluray-x264-dts-mt/', 'pubDate': 'Thu, 23 Feb 2023 00:33:03 +0000', 'category': 'Movies'}
2023-02-22 17:07:50 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://log.rlsbb.cc/feed/>
{'title': 'Devotion 2022 720p BluRay x264 DTS-MT', 'link': 'https://log.rlsbb.cc/devotion-2022-720p-bluray-x264-dts-mt/', 'pubDate': 'Wed, 22 Feb 2023 23:55:04 +0000', 'category': 'Movies'}
2023-02-22 17:07:50 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://log.rlsbb.cc/feed/>
{'title': 'Gods Country 2022 720p BluRay DTS x264-MT', 'link': 'https://log.rlsbb.cc/gods-country-2022-720p-bluray-dts-x264-mt/', 'pubDate': 'Wed, 22 Feb 2023 23:30:47 +0000', 'category': 'Movies'}
2023-02-22 17:07:50 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://log.rlsbb.cc/feed/>
{'title': 'Doctor 2012 1080p AMZN WEBRip x264-PTerWEB', 'link': 'https://log.rlsbb.cc/doctor-2012-1080p-amzn-webrip-x264-pterweb/', 'pubDate': 'Wed, 22 Feb 2023 23:26:45 +0000', 'category': 'Foreign M
ovies'}
2023-02-22 17:07:50 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://log.rlsbb.cc/feed/>
{'title': 'Nobadi 2019 1080p HMAX WEBRip x264-NGP', 'link': 'https://log.rlsbb.cc/nobadi-2019-1080p-hmax-webrip-x264-ngp/', 'pubDate': 'Wed, 22 Feb 2023 23:26:03 +0000', 'category': 'Foreign Movies'}
2023-02-22 17:07:50 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://log.rlsbb.cc/feed/>
{'title': 'Naked News 2023.02.22 1080p WEB x264-NGP', 'link': 'https://log.rlsbb.cc/naked-news-2023-02-22-1080p-web-x264-ngp/', 'pubDate': 'Wed, 22 Feb 2023 23:25:41 +0000', 'category': 'TV Shows'}
2023-02-22 17:07:50 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://log.rlsbb.cc/feed/>
{'title': 'Brice de Nice 2005 2160p UHD BluRay H265-GAZPROM', 'link': 'https://log.rlsbb.cc/brice-de-nice-2005-2160p-uhd-bluray-h265-gazprom/', 'pubDate': 'Wed, 22 Feb 2023 23:25:34 +0000', 'category'
: 'Foreign Movies'}
2023-02-22 17:07:50 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://log.rlsbb.cc/feed/>
{'title': 'NOVA S50E04 720p WEB h264-BAE', 'link': 'https://log.rlsbb.cc/nova-s50e04-720p-web-h264-bae/', 'pubDate': 'Wed, 22 Feb 2023 23:05:51 +0000', 'category': 'TV Shows'}
2023-02-22 17:07:50 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://log.rlsbb.cc/feed/>
{'title': 'Run the Burbs S02E08 720p WEBRip x264-BAE', 'link': 'https://log.rlsbb.cc/run-the-burbs-s02e08-720p-webrip-x264-bae/', 'pubDate': 'Wed, 22 Feb 2023 23:05:34 +0000', 'category': 'TV Shows'}
2023-02-22 17:07:50 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://log.rlsbb.cc/feed/>
{'title': 'Empire of Light 2022 1080p BluRay x264-PiGNUS', 'link': 'https://log.rlsbb.cc/empire-of-light-2022-1080p-bluray-x264-pignus/', 'pubDate': 'Wed, 22 Feb 2023 23:04:18 +0000', 'category': 'Mov
ies'}
2023-02-22 17:07:50 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://log.rlsbb.cc/feed/>
{'title': 'Dark Land Hunting The Killers S02E01 720p WEB x264-CiTiDeL', 'link': 'https://log.rlsbb.cc/dark-land-hunting-the-killers-s02e01-720p-web-x264-citidel/', 'pubDate': 'Wed, 22 Feb 2023 22:21:2
5 +0000', 'category': 'TV Shows'}
2023-02-22 17:07:50 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://log.rlsbb.cc/feed/>
{'title': 'Caught Red Handed S11E03 720p WEB x264-CiTiDeL', 'link': 'https://log.rlsbb.cc/caught-red-handed-s11e03-720p-web-x264-citidel/', 'pubDate': 'Wed, 22 Feb 2023 22:19:47 +0000', 'category': 'T
V Shows'}
2023-02-22 17:07:50 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://log.rlsbb.cc/feed/>
{'title': 'The Magnificent Seven 1960 2160p UHD BluRay x265-B0MBARDiERS', 'link': 'https://log.rlsbb.cc/the-magnificent-seven-1960-2160p-uhd-bluray-x265-b0mbardiers/', 'pubDate': 'Wed, 22 Feb 2023 22:
19:17 +0000', 'category': 'Movies'}
2023-02-22 17:07:50 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://log.rlsbb.cc/feed/>
{'title': 'Empire of Light 2022 720p BluRay x264-PiGNUS', 'link': 'https://log.rlsbb.cc/empire-of-light-2022-720p-bluray-x264-pignus/', 'pubDate': 'Wed, 22 Feb 2023 22:18:57 +0000', 'category': 'Movie
s'}
2023-02-22 17:07:50 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://log.rlsbb.cc/feed/>
{'title': 'Empire of Light 2022 BDRip x264-PiGNUS', 'link': 'https://log.rlsbb.cc/empire-of-light-2022-bdrip-x264-pignus/', 'pubDate': 'Wed, 22 Feb 2023 22:18:36 +0000', 'category': 'Movies'}
2023-02-22 17:07:50 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://log.rlsbb.cc/feed/>
{'title': 'The Absolute Truth With Emerald Robinson 2023.02.21 PNO Web-DL H264-DonJuan', 'link': 'https://log.rlsbb.cc/the-absolute-truth-with-emerald-robinson-2023-02-21-pno-web-dl-h264-donjuan/', 'p
ubDate': 'Wed, 22 Feb 2023 22:15:48 +0000', 'category': 'TV Shows'}
2023-02-22 17:07:50 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://log.rlsbb.cc/feed/>
{'title': 'Tucker Carlson Tonight 2023.02.21 PNO Web-DL H264-DonJuan', 'link': 'https://log.rlsbb.cc/tucker-carlson-tonight-2023-02-21-pno-web-dl-h264-donjuan/', 'pubDate': 'Wed, 22 Feb 2023 22:15:47
+0000', 'category': 'TV Shows'}
2023-02-22 17:07:50 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://log.rlsbb.cc/feed/>
{'title': 'The Five 2011 2023 02 21 SN Web-DL H264-DonJuan', 'link': 'https://log.rlsbb.cc/the-five-2011-2023-02-21-sn-web-dl-h264-donjuan/', 'pubDate': 'Wed, 22 Feb 2023 22:15:47 +0000', 'category':
'TV Shows'}
2023-02-22 17:07:50 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://log.rlsbb.cc/feed/>
{'title': 'The Ingraham Angle 2023.02.21 PNO Web-DL H264-DonJuan', 'link': 'https://log.rlsbb.cc/the-ingraham-angle-2023-02-21-pno-web-dl-h264-donjuan/', 'pubDate': 'Wed, 22 Feb 2023 22:15:46 +0000',
'category': 'TV Shows'}
2023-02-22 17:07:50 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://log.rlsbb.cc/feed/>
{'title': 'Stinchfield Tonight 2023.02.21 PNO Web-DL H264-DonJuan', 'link': 'https://log.rlsbb.cc/stinchfield-tonight-2023-02-21-pno-web-dl-h264-donjuan/', 'pubDate': 'Wed, 22 Feb 2023 22:13:03 +0000'
, 'category': 'TV Shows'}
2023-02-22 17:07:50 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://log.rlsbb.cc/feed/>
{'title': 'Jesse Watters Primetime 2023.02.21 SN Web-DL H264-DonJuan', 'link': 'https://log.rlsbb.cc/jesse-watters-primetime-2023-02-21-sn-web-dl-h264-donjuan/', 'pubDate': 'Wed, 22 Feb 2023 22:12:58
+0000', 'category': 'TV Shows'}
2023-02-22 17:07:50 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://log.rlsbb.cc/feed/>
{'title': 'Hannity 2023.02.21 PNO Web-DL H264-DonJuan', 'link': 'https://log.rlsbb.cc/hannity-2023-02-21-pno-web-dl-h264-donjuan/', 'pubDate': 'Wed, 22 Feb 2023 22:12:48 +0000', 'category': 'TV Shows'
}
2023-02-22 17:07:50 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://log.rlsbb.cc/feed/>
{'title': 'Gutfeld 2023.02.21 PNO Web-DL H264-DonJuan', 'link': 'https://log.rlsbb.cc/gutfeld-2023-02-21-pno-web-dl-h264-donjuan/', 'pubDate': 'Wed, 22 Feb 2023 22:12:47 +0000', 'category': 'TV Shows'
}
2023-02-22 17:07:50 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://log.rlsbb.cc/feed/>
{'title': 'Fox News At Night 2023.02.21 PNO Web-DL H264-DonJuan', 'link': 'https://log.rlsbb.cc/fox-news-at-night-2023-02-21-pno-web-dl-h264-donjuan/', 'pubDate': 'Wed, 22 Feb 2023 22:12:36 +0000', 'c
ategory': 'TV Shows'}
2023-02-22 17:07:50 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://log.rlsbb.cc/feed/>
{'title': 'The Bold and the Beautiful S36E104 1080p WEB h264-DiRT', 'link': 'https://log.rlsbb.cc/the-bold-and-the-beautiful-s36e104-1080p-web-h264-dirt/', 'pubDate': 'Wed, 22 Feb 2023 21:56:22 +0000'
, 'category': 'TV Shows'}
2023-02-22 17:07:50 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://log.rlsbb.cc/feed/>
{'title': 'The Comic 1985 BDRip x264-GAZER', 'link': 'https://log.rlsbb.cc/the-comic-1985-bdrip-x264-gazer/', 'pubDate': 'Wed, 22 Feb 2023 21:56:12 +0000', 'category': 'Movies'}
2023-02-22 17:07:50 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://log.rlsbb.cc/feed/>
{'title': 'The Comic 1985 720p BluRay x264-GAZER', 'link': 'https://log.rlsbb.cc/the-comic-1985-720p-bluray-x264-gazer/', 'pubDate': 'Wed, 22 Feb 2023 21:56:03 +0000', 'category': 'Movies'}
2023-02-22 17:07:50 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://log.rlsbb.cc/feed/>
{'title': 'The Comic 1985 1080p BluRay x264-GAZER', 'link': 'https://log.rlsbb.cc/the-comic-1985-1080p-bluray-x264-gazer/', 'pubDate': 'Wed, 22 Feb 2023 21:55:52 +0000', 'category': 'Movies'}
2023-02-22 17:07:50 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://log.rlsbb.cc/feed/>
{'title': 'Great British Menu S18E11 WEB-DL x264-JiVE', 'link': 'https://log.rlsbb.cc/great-british-menu-s18e11-web-dl-x264-jive/', 'pubDate': 'Wed, 22 Feb 2023 21:29:30 +0000', 'category': 'TV Shows'
}
2023-02-22 17:07:50 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://log.rlsbb.cc/feed/>
{'title': 'Detective Knight Redemption 2022 720p BluRay x264-WoAT', 'link': 'https://log.rlsbb.cc/detective-knight-redemption-2022-720p-bluray-x264-woat/', 'pubDate': 'Wed, 22 Feb 2023 20:28:25 +0000'
, 'category': 'Movies'}
2023-02-22 17:07:50 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://log.rlsbb.cc/feed/>
{'title': 'Detective Knight Redemption 2022 1080p BluRay x264-WoAT', 'link': 'https://log.rlsbb.cc/detective-knight-redemption-2022-1080p-bluray-x264-woat/', 'pubDate': 'Wed, 22 Feb 2023 20:26:55 +000
0', 'category': 'Movies'}
2023-02-22 17:07:50 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://log.rlsbb.cc/feed/>
{'title': 'Among The Living 2022 1080p BluRay x264-GETiT', 'link': 'https://log.rlsbb.cc/among-the-living-2022-1080p-bluray-x264-getit/', 'pubDate': 'Wed, 22 Feb 2023 20:20:15 +0000', 'category': 'Mov
ies'}
2023-02-22 17:07:50 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://log.rlsbb.cc/feed/>
{'title': 'The Beat With Ari Melber 2023.02.21 WEB x264-Anon', 'link': 'https://log.rlsbb.cc/the-beat-with-ari-melber-2023-02-21-web-x264-anon/', 'pubDate': 'Wed, 22 Feb 2023 20:16:38 +0000', 'categor
y': 'TV Shows'}
2023-02-22 17:07:50 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://log.rlsbb.cc/feed/>
{'title': 'The Young and the Restless S50E101 720p WEB h264-DiRT', 'link': 'https://log.rlsbb.cc/the-young-and-the-restless-s50e101-720p-web-h264-dirt/', 'pubDate': 'Wed, 22 Feb 2023 19:52:35 +0000',
'category': 'TV Shows'}
2023-02-22 17:07:50 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://log.rlsbb.cc/feed/>
{'title': 'Property Brothers Forever Home S08E01 WEB-DL x264-JiVE', 'link': 'https://log.rlsbb.cc/property-brothers-forever-home-s08e01-web-dl-x264-jive/', 'pubDate': 'Wed, 22 Feb 2023 19:28:27 +0000'
, 'category': 'TV Shows'}
2023-02-22 17:07:50 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://log.rlsbb.cc/feed/>
{'title': 'This Hour Has 22 Minutes S30E19 WEB-DL x264-JiVE', 'link': 'https://log.rlsbb.cc/this-hour-has-22-minutes-s30e19-web-dl-x264-jive/', 'pubDate': 'Wed, 22 Feb 2023 19:28:07 +0000', 'category'
: 'TV Shows'}
2023-02-22 17:07:50 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://log.rlsbb.cc/feed/>
{'title': 'The Nate And Jeremiah Home Project S02E01 WEB-DL x264-JiVE', 'link': 'https://log.rlsbb.cc/the-nate-and-jeremiah-home-project-s02e01-web-dl-x264-jive/', 'pubDate': 'Wed, 22 Feb 2023 19:28:0
3 +0000', 'category': 'TV Shows'}
2023-02-22 17:07:50 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped fro
```

Comment: I don't get it because I want the filters in the cookie, so that I can get only those categories.In your case did you get lucky that the items you got obeyed the filters?

Comment: Thanks Dude, worked like a charm. Ran it now and saw that a non-filter item was ignored.
So the trick was to just include the cookie and not the header.
Cheers.